# Remove from array PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I use `preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches)` regularly on data, and basically, I always need to remove either £0.00 or $0.00 or €0.00 from the array should it be in there.

I never know the position within the array that it will be in, if at all.

I've tried `unset($matches['£0.00'])` and `unset($matches[0]['£0.00'])` but didn't work

Also, can it be done without using the actual currency symbol and maybe regex `\p{Sc}`

So, summary, I have an array of numbers with currency symbols, and need to remove any zero entries.

sample array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => £18.99 [1] => £0.00 [2] => £0.00 [3] => £0.00 ) )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: can you show us sample array structure?

Comment: @MuthuKumaran - hi, added sample

Comment: Why don't you modify your `$pattern` to not match those in the first place?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usage of `preg_match()` and `preg_match_all()` sometimes can be weird

`$matches` will be array of the matches to the pattern - in this instance if you

```
preg_match("/\p{Sc}0\.00/","£0.00",$matches);
//$matches[0] => £0.00
```

or if you add parenthesis `()` to the pattern you can extract a part

```
preg_match("/\p{Sc}(0\.00)/","£0.00",$matches);
//$matches[0] => £0.00
//$matches[1] => 0.00
```

so to solve this problem try this

```
foreach($sample_array as $key => $value)
{
     if(preg_match("/(\$|\p{Sc})0\.00/",$value))
     {
          unset($sample_array[$key]);
     }
}
```

Notice the pipe `|` that denotes `$` or `£` - if you add another pipe for the euro symbol it will capture that as well - also notice that we are `unset()`-ing a key in the original array instead of `unset()`-ing the `$matches` array

Comment: Thanks for this, is it then possible I could just change my original pattern to stop it at source instead of running preg_match again? Current pattern: $pattern = '/\p{Sc}\s*\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?/u';

Comment: possibly - it looks like you are getting the numbers out in 2 separate parenthesis - check the value of `$matches` by doing a `var_dump($matches)` or `print_r($matches)`

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_element($arr, $val)

        {

            foreach ($arr as $key => $value)

            {

                if ($arr[$key] == $val)

                {

                unset($arr[$key]);

                }

            }

            return $arr = array_values($arr);

        }
```

You can use this function these function returns the array elements after delete the specified value.